# Is it possible to link object files generated from the Go toolchain using gcc/clang linker?

Tags: go, go-toolchain

executable files built by the Go compiler are not compatible on target environment as the loader expects program sections to be in specific order.

As a result, I'm trying to compile the Go source using `go tool compile` to generate `.o` files, which I want to link using the `gcc/clang` linker option instead of `go tool link`

Does the object files generated from go build are compatible to be linked with `gcc/clang` toolchain ?

Comment: Instead of invoking gc or the linker you should try `buildmode`: Run `go help buildmode` for details.

Comment: @Volker thanks, I was able to create a static or shared library from this option. But, this includes a lot of go runtime in the built library. If I have to link this library along with other libraries built using clang, this would not resolve the symbols as the statically built library has gcc symbols:
`/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: stderr
>>> referenced by gcc_libinit.c:29`
Is there a way to build go runtime without glibc symbols, so that I can use the archive without relying gcc toolchain ?

Comment: You probably should ask this on the golang-nuts mailing list and not here.